Repeated corruption issue with bitcoind
I'm trying to index the entire chain for spent P2PK inputs for this program I'm writing, and whenever I get to this transaction - 7a8394fd438d9fbe6b36ce38e5b0ca65037f864d1007236775ac3532b886ebe1 - I get this error:
Error: JSON-RPC error: RPC error response: RpcError { code: -1, message: "Fatal LevelDB error: Corruption: block checksum mismatch: /mnt/Node/bitcoind-mainnet/indexes/txindex/490706.ldb", data: None }
I've already tried the -reindex option. I'm not sure what else to try to recover from this, and I'm not sure what caused it. I'm going to reset the directory and see if that resolves the issue, but I'm not sure how it could be prevented in the future.
This is on Arch Linux with the datadir kept on an ext4 SSD.

Are you sure that after the reindex, you get a failure at exactly the same transaction?

Yes, however I later noticed that there was a block checksum error with leveldb. I'm currently doing an IBD on a different disk, in the hopes that it might just be a hardware issue.

The leveldb block checksum mismatch still happens. This time during IBD. I'm going to file a bug report for this on Bitcoin Core.
